# UImages loading speed

Tags: ipad, ios5

I need lots of small images (about 200 pcs) in my app. Image's resolution are 20-200 x 20-200 pixels. Loading time is 30-40 secs :(
How to accelerate?

I need all images, so I think so have to "lazy load".
I use NSOperations... it's cool, User Interface works when app loading images... but 35 sec.
Loading code:

```
    - (void)loadImage
{
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: name];
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Would be faster if I used Main Bundle?
or I pack small files in one big file? (other my app load 10 HD images 2 secs)

re,
Tom.

Comment: I read PNG photoshop bug... I cleared meta data... -2-3 secs, I try main bundle same loading time... 200 small PNG loading 35 secs.
PNG's about 4,7MB, I try non compressed PNG, 12MB but loading time same 35 sec.
I don't understand... Ipad loads 15 1MB max compressed PNG (15MB) 1-2 secs, 190 small PNG summa 5MB 30 secs.

Comment: I store image names in txt file. I change file encoding and problem is solved.